# What is a bolo roast.

Tags: cut-of-meat, african

I'm trying to make bultong (South African meat jerky) for a friend from there and he said I need bolo. What cut of meat would this be in America?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information provided by both Paparazzi's answer and logophobe's comment is correct. The bolo is from the forequarter of the cow, specifically from the shoulder area.

I don't know of one single whole cut in the US that would encompass the whole bolo roast. However, we have three cuts that make up the three primary parts of the bolo roast.

- Round bolo = mock tender roast
- Shoulder bolo = shoulder roast
- Side bolo = boneless blade roast

This picture shows it quite well. (Cropped to remove ads.)

[image]

And this picture shows the three pieces together as a whole bolo roast:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Bolo](https://beefmaster.co.za/products/beef-cuts/bolo/)

> The bolo (triceps muscle) is the muscle, which lies posterior to the
>   shoulder joint and ventral to the spine of the scapula. The thick end
>   of the bolo commencing at the meat inspection cut includes all muscles
>   overlying the first natural muscle division and the thinner end
>   includes all the muscles overlying the rear portion of the blade bone
>   (scapula).

Comment: This is a tricky one because there doesn't appear to be a direct equivalent American beef cut. It's somewhere in-between (or overlapping) part of the bottom chuck and the flat brisket.